# 'First Sun of the month' TODOs disappear from agenda even when not done

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I can schedule a TODO on the first Sun of the month like so:

```
*** TODO  Pay bill                                   :Monthly:
SCHEDULED: <%%(diary-float t 0 1)>
```

This shows in the Agenda for the first Sun of the month. But if not done, it does not appear in the agenda for the next day --- unlike other tasks with a simple `SCHEDULED: <2017-11-05 Sun>` entries.

How do I ensure that the 'First Sun of the month' TODOs continue to appear in the agenda till done?